# Unable to freedraw perfectly in all directions using Fabricjs

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am trying to free draw a circle in Fabricjs awesome library , but I am getting some issue when it comes to free draw a circle.
I am able to achieve the same for Rectangle free drawing but failing to achieve perfection when drawing a circle.

Here's the code :
`

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas2');

```
var circle, isDown, origX, origY;

canvas.on('mouse:down', function(o){
    isDown = true;
    var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
    origX = pointer.x;
    origY = pointer.y;
    circle = new fabric.Circle({
    left: origX,
    top: origY,
    originX: 'left',
    originY: 'top',
    radius: pointer.x-origX,
    angle: 0,
    fill: '',
    stroke:'red',
    strokeWidth:3,
    });
    canvas.add(circle);
});

canvas.on('mouse:move', function(o){
    if (!isDown) return;
    var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);

    if(origX>pointer.x){
    circle.set({ left: Math.abs(pointer.x) });
    }
    if(origY>pointer.y){
    circle.set({ top: Math.abs(pointer.y) });
    }

    circle.set({ radius: Math.abs(origY - pointer.y)/2 });


    canvas.renderAll();
});

canvas.on('mouse:up', function(o){
  isDown = false;
});
```

`

Here's the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8u1cqasa/9/)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look my updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/8u1cqasa/10/

I modified your mouse:move function to take in account of position and strokeWidth;

```
canvas.on('mouse:move', function(o){
    if (!isDown) return;
    var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
    var radius = Math.abs(origY - pointer.y)/2;
    if (radius > circle.strokeWidth) {
        radius -= circle.strokeWidth/2;
    }
    circle.set({ radius: radius});

    if(origX>pointer.x){
        circle.set({originX: 'right' });
    } else {
        circle.set({originX: 'left' });
    }
    if(origY>pointer.y){
        circle.set({originY: 'bottom'  });
    } else {
        circle.set({originY: 'top'  });
    }
    canvas.renderAll();
});
```